# Solving differential-difference equation using Fourier series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

> Determine a solution with period $2$ of the differential-difference equation $$y'(t)+y(t-1) = \cos^2 \pi t$$

**Attempted solution**

The r.h. side can be rewritten as $\cos^2 \pi t = \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{4}e^{2\pi i t} + \dfrac{1}{4}e^{-2\pi i t}$. With period $2P = 2$ we determine the fundamental angular frequency $\Omega$ is $\Omega = \pi/P = \pi$.  We thus look for a solution $y$ such that $y(t) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} c_n e^{i n\Omega t} = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}c_n e^{in \pi t}$, noting that $y(t+2) =y(t)$. Inserting our assertion in the original equation we conclude $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} in \pi c_n \pi e^{in \pi t} + \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} c_ne^{in\pi(t-1)} = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} (in \pi+(-1)^n)c_ne^{in\pi t}  = \dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}e^{2\pi i t}+\dfrac{1}{4}e^{-2\pi i t}$$
From this we conclude that $c_n = 0$ for all $n\neq 0, \pm 2$. For $n=0$ we obtain $c_0 =1/2$ and for $n=\pm 2$ we obtain $c_{\pm 2} = \dfrac{1}{4(1 \pm 2 \pi i)}$. Our solution is therefore $y(t) = \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{4+8\pi i}e^{2 \pi i t}+ \dfrac{1}{4-8\pi i } e^{-2 \pi i t}$

**The problem**

I think my solution is correct, at least for the values I tested. However, it is apparent that the period is $1$, not the desired $2$. Where did I go wrong and how can I remedy it?

Comment: Any function with period $1$ also has period $2$.

Comment: To reinforce the point: The above solution has least period 1, and therefore period 2 as well. The question, then, is whether there's a solution with least period 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $1$-periodic function is also $2$-periodic, only that the minimal period is not $2$. And note that the forcing term,
$$
\cos^2\pi t=\frac12(\cos(2\pi t)+1),
$$
that drives the stable solutions, also has period $1$.

---

For any 2-periodic solution, one also has that $y'(t-1)+y(t-2)=y'(t-1)+y(t)=\cos^2(\pi t)$ so that $g_\pm(t)=y(t)\pm y(t-1)$ satisfy the ordinary differential equations
\begin{align}
g_+'(t)+g_+(t)&=2\cos^2(πt),\\
g_-'(t)-g_-(t)&=0
\end{align}
where again the periodic solutions can not contain any exponential terms so that $g_+(t)=A+B\cos2\pi t+C\sin 2\pi t$ and $g_-(t)=0$.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Does that mean that we cannot construct a solution with minimal period $2$? And if we can, how would we set out to find it?

Comment: This would only be possible if the homogeneous equation had stable 2-periodic solutions. I added a section that shows that this is not the case, as any periodic solution is the sum of two solutions of linear first order ODE, where all non-trivial solutions are not stable (= bounded over all of $\Bbb R$)..

Comment: It seems like from $g_{-}(t)=0$ one has $f(t)=f(t-1)$ i.e. every 2-periodic solution must also be 1-periodic. If that's what you intended, it seems worth highlighting.

Comment: This is a consequence of the right side $f(t)=\cos^2\pi t$ being 1-periodic, If the right side were 2-periodic, then none of the right sides $f(t)\pm f(t-1)$ in the equations for $g_\pm$ would cancel to zero.